# Apple rejected my app due to crash, can't reproduce it 4

Tags: ios, crash, exc-bad-access, appstore-approval

I uploaded app several times on apple store but they rejected because of crash but I could not reproduce it. 
They provide me to step where the app is crashing but on my all devices app is working fine.

We have tested on multiple ipad devices and all ipad simulators in IPv6 connection. We were not able to reproduce the issue that you experienced.

We could not reproduce the issue even once on our devices and simulators. Please provide more details about crash report.

They rejected the app because of a crash I can't reproduce. They sent me this crash report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18183b164 0x180a84528 0x1817d3c9c 0x181703640 0x1010bf724 0x18221fd58 0x1817e3dc0 0x1817e3ae4 0x1817e32e4 0x1817e0ecc 0x181700c58 0x1835acf84 0x18ae595c4 0x1010a3098 0x18122056c)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001813502e8 0x18132e000 + 140008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001814652f8 0x181462000 + 13048
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001812befbc 0x18125c000 + 405436
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180a5b068 0x180a59000 + 8296
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180a5b210 0x180a59000 + 8720
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180a84810 0x180a7c000 + 34832
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180a7354c 0x180a59000 + 107852
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180a73158 0x180a59000 + 106840
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180a846e8 0x180a7c000 + 34536
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181700cc4 0x1816f8000 + 36036
10  GraphicsServices                0x00000001835acf84 0x1835a2000 + 44932
11  UIKit                           0x000000018ae595c4 0x18ade6000 + 472516
12  Ref.Editor                      0x00000001010a3098 0x10109c000 + 28824
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018122056c 0x18121f000 + 5484

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181350d80 0x18132e000 + 142720
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181462eec 0x181462000 + 3820
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181462b6c 0x181462000 + 2924

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181350d80 0x18132e000 + 142720
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181462eec 0x181462000 + 3820
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181462b6c 0x181462000 + 2924

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181350d80 0x18132e000 + 142720
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181463080 0x181462000 + 4224
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181462b6c 0x181462000 + 2924

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181350d80 0x18132e000 + 142720
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181462eec 0x181462000 + 3820
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181462b6c 0x181462000 + 2924

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181350d80 0x18132e000 + 142720
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181463080 0x181462000 + 4224
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181462b6c 0x181462000 + 2924

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018132f568 0x18132e000 + 5480
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018132f3e0 0x18132e000 + 5088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001817e3108 0x1816f8000 + 962824
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001817e0cd4 0x1816f8000 + 953556
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181700c58 0x1816f8000 + 35928
5   Foundation                      0x0000000182135594 0x182129000 + 50580
6   Foundation                      0x00000001821549ac 0x182129000 + 178604
7   UIKit                           0x000000018b9c37a8 0x18ade6000 + 12441512
8   Foundation                      0x00000001822370f4 0x182129000 + 1106164
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001814642b4 0x181462000 + 8884
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181464180 0x181462000 + 8576
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181462b74 0x181462000 + 2932

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001813500f0 0x18132e000 + 139504
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181466ce4 0x181462000 + 19684
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000180a06f34 0x1809ff000 + 32564
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000188ba9168 0x1881ff000 + 10133864
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000188ba903c 0x1881ff000 + 10133564
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000188ba8ec0 0x1881ff000 + 10133184
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000188ba91b8 0x1881ff000 + 10133944
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001814642b4 0x181462000 + 8884
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181464180 0x181462000 + 8576
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181462b74 0x181462000 + 2932

Thread 8 name:  WebThread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001813500f0 0x18132e000 + 139504
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181466ce4 0x181462000 + 19684
2   WebCore                         0x000000018968b09c 0x189634000 + 356508
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018184081c 0x1816f8000 + 1345564
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181725ccc 0x1816f8000 + 187596
5   WebKitLegacy                    0x000000018ab0f6d8 0x18aa52000 + 775896
6   WebCore                         0x000000018a3c477c 0x189634000 + 14223228
7   WebCore                         0x0000000189b60370 0x189634000 + 5423984
8   WebCore                         0x0000000189b5f3b8 0x189634000 + 5419960
9   WebCore                         0x0000000189b5e290 0x189634000 + 5415568
10  WebCore                         0x0000000189b5c374 0x189634000 + 5407604
11  WebCore                         0x0000000189b5bfa4 0x189634000 + 5406628
12  WebCore                         0x000000018a35fb08 0x189634000 + 13810440
13  WebCore                         0x000000018a35e54c 0x189634000 + 13804876
14  WebCore                         0x0000000189643e18 0x189634000 + 65048
15  WebCore                         0x0000000189643d58 0x189634000 + 64856
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001817e3dc0 0x1816f8000 + 966080
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001817e3ae4 0x1816f8000 + 965348
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001817e32e4 0x1816f8000 + 963300
19  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001817e0ecc 0x1816f8000 + 954060
20  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181700c58 0x1816f8000 + 35928
21  WebCore                         0x000000018967584c 0x189634000 + 268364
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001814642b4 0x181462000 + 8884
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181464180 0x181462000 + 8576
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181462b74 0x181462000 + 2932
```

Comment: You need to [Symbolicate the crash log](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) in order to determine where the crash occurred in your app.

Comment: how can i detemine Symbolicate the crash log ?

Comment: Click on the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the archive file & code which you used while uploading the app you can reproduce/symbolicate the crash using below-mentioned steps/screen-shots.

Go to Window->Organizer->Select your project->go to Crashes->Select crash you want to open->Open in project->Choose your project.
[image]

Comment: I didn't got any crashes yet. :(